# Comparing 2 model numbers to see if price matches

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 2 excel sheets with product models and price, one from our online store and one from our accounting software.

Not all the models that are online are in the accounting software and vice versa.

I want to be able to compare the model numbers, and if they match to compare the price which is in the other column (looking for price discrepancies).

I believe this can be written with a `VLOOKUP`, but I keep getting circular references when trying. To make this easier I copied all the columns onto 1 sheet. so it is 1 sheet with 4 colums

> A:Model
>   B:Price
>   C:Model
>   D:Price

Here is what I have so far: `=VLOOKUP(A2,$C$2:$C$1192,D2,FALSE)`

I am getting mostly `#N/A` but also a bunch of `#REF!`. Pretty sure the `#REF` is where there is a match in the array, but for some reason I am getting a circular refference?

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The second argument of `VLOOKUP` must contain a range where the first column is the key you are looking for AND the columns where the corresponding value is located. In your case, it should include columns C (key) and D (value).
- The third argument of `VLOOKUP` is the column **number**. In this case, 2, (C is one, D is 2).

So in your case, the formula would look like:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,$C$2:$D$1192,2,FALSE)
```

Comment: Doh. So obvious especially when I'm looking at how to use the vlookup function. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The vlookup requires that you use the index of the column you want to return, so instead of D2, you'd have to put a number.  Also, the column you want to return has to be part of the range.  The best way to do this is to use:  =VLOOKUP(A2, $C$2:$D$1992, 2, false).

Comment: Sorry for the duplicate response.  I would also suggest using named ranges with vlookup functions.  In this case, you could name the range C2:D1192 as "acct_software" (or "online" if it's online data), and then your vlookup would look like this:  =VLOOKUP(A2,acct_software,2,false).  There also isn't a need to have your two ranges on the same tab or next to each other.  You could also run vlookups against both ranges, and then you'd know where you didn't have matches on each side.

Comment: 3 minutes late! Thanks for your help though!